# Is It possible to make a string reverse using css without using "rtl" ?

Tags: css

Is It possible to make a string reverse using css without using "rtl" ? Example:- "Hello World" to "World Hello"

Comment: depending on your code we can find some *workarounds*

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple answer: **No**

CSS is used for styling. 
Use Javascript for text manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but the words "Hello and World" should be in 2 separate tags. Then you can try using css flexbox. Below is the example for your reference:
[Reverse Element Order with CSS Flexbox](https://davidwalsh.name/css-reverse)